# Custom style page for qt quick QML aplications (like HTML and CSS)

Tags: qt, styles, qml, qtquick2, qtquick-designer

Is possible to create a custom style file in QT and apply it for all QML files (like CSS does applies to HTML )?

Is there any "class" declaration for QML ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to declare a "class" in QML you have to create new QML file. Its name must begin with a capital letter. You can also create custom objects using C++ but probably that is not what you are looking for.

Let's say you want to create custom `Text` element so the text is always centered and fits the given dimensions. So you create a file named *CustomText.qml* and write:

```
/* CustomText.qml file */    

import QtQuick 2.0

Text {
    id: customText
    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
    clip: true
    fontSizeMode: Text.Fit
    font.pixelSize: height
    wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
    minimumPixelSize: 3
    color: "black"

    /* using these lines you can set custom font loaded from a file */
//    font.family: customFont.name
//    FontLoader {
//        id: customFont
//        source: "qrc:/myCustomFont.ttf"
//    }
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
/* main.qml file */
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true

    width: 300
    height: 300

    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle1
        color: "lightgrey"
        x: 5
        y: 5
        width: 200
        height: 50

        CustomText {
            anchors.fill: parent
            text: "testing custom text object"
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle2
        color: "lightgrey"
        anchors.left: rectangle1.left
        anchors.top: rectangle1.bottom
        anchors.topMargin: 5
        width: 50
        height: 50

        CustomText {
            anchors.fill: parent
            text: "testing custom text object"
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle3
        color: "lightgrey"
        anchors.left: rectangle2.left
        anchors.top: rectangle2.bottom
        anchors.topMargin: 5
        width: 100
        height: 100

        CustomText {
            anchors.fill: parent
            text: "testing custom text object"
        }
    }
}
```

That is how it would look like:

[image: image showing example code in action]

Comment: what If, from now on, every element must use a Green font color.? must I create a custom QML for every element? I would like to take an existent project and, somehow, change it's style

Comment: @DanielSantos Unfortunately yes. You would have to manually change every `Text` to `CustomText` and in it set `color: "green"`.